# Generating crema with a moka pot?

Tags: crema, moka

I have a stove top percolator for making espresso.  It does not generate any crema.  it possible to do so with a stove top percolator?

Comment: Is it one of those small sort of mini alembic types?

Comment: it is a mini type

Answer (score 12):

Moka pots (or stove top percolators) usually produce a pressure of around 1.5 bar, while most coffees require a pressure of at least around 6 bar for a crema to appear. However, there are some Moka pots with a special valve (called Cremator) which helps creating more pressures and thus produce a crema.

By the way, a *real Espresso* has to be brewed with a pressure of 9 bar ± 1, according to the [Italian National Espresso Institute](http://www.espressoitaliano.org/files/File/istituzionale_inei_hq_en.pdf), so it can't be brewed with a Moka pot.

Answer (score -2):

i read that the coffee bean type makes the difference. 100% arabica beans make no creama, while robusta beans do, however arabica tastes better, so mixing the 2 types will make a good tasting coffee and crema. problem is mixing. lavazza sells already mixed in one bag w/ different combinations of each bean. other important variables are grind size and water temp. the more u read about it the more u will realize that espresso is an elusive and difficult drink to make at home. the espresso gurus say the type of pot/machine is not as important as type of grind and grinder. ck out
https://prima-coffee.com/learn/article/making-espresso
if u want crema and no guess work, try out a nespresso machine and coffees. expensive but worth it if espresso and coffee are your drinks of choice.

Comment: Could you provide evidence that arabica beans do not provide creama while robusta beans do.

Comment: It's a fallacy to say that all arabica does not make a crema on an espresso shot. It does.
Robusta does it better which is why most Italian espresso blends have a small percentage (probably under 10%) mixed in. It's usually not higher because of the "off" flavor of robusta. Robusta is also higher in caffeine than arabica. Very few, if any American espresso blends have any robusta because of the flavor. You will still find a crema on it though.
Most home espresso machines fail to make a good crema for many reasons. 1) bad grind
2) too little pressure in the machine 3) bad procedure (i.e. uneven